# How to show waiting indicator while connection is cheecking in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a Login page in react native using PHP as BackEnd(where I fetch my sql data) ,

My problem is when I write my username and password and I click my connection button, I need to show to users that I'm working on his connection .

I want to show dialog box while traitements of query complete

```
 export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
       super(props);}

    userRegister = () =>{
      const usermail = this.state.usermail;
      const password = this.state.password;
   fetch('http://192.168.1.2:80/netOne/recup.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{'Accept':'application/json','Content-type' :'application/json'},
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password,})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
   .then((responseJson)=>{
   if(responseJson =='Data Matched'){
     this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Welcome')}
   else{alert(JSON.stringify("Merci de saisir des données convenables"));}})
   .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
         style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
         source={require('./netOne.jpg')}
       />
            <View style={styles.pass}>
            <Text style={{marginTop:20 , color:'grey'}}>Username :</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder={this.state.placeholder1} style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}}
            onChangeText= {usermail=>this.setState({usermail })}/>
             </View>

            <View style={styles.pass}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:20 , color:'grey'}}>Password :</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder={this.state.placeholder2} style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
        onChangeText= {password=>this.setState({password})}
        />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.secure} style={{margin:20}}>
            <Icon name="eye" size={20}  /></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}>
                <Text>Connexion</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>
        );

    }

}
```

I need something like this !! please if you can help  me 
[image]

Comment: you will want to set up a loading state.  you could initialize it to true once the user clicks the login button and then set it to false once you get a response from your ```fetch```.  You will also want to make sure that the login modal is being activated within your render method if it is set to true and then disabled when it is set to false.

Comment: Hello I did what you  said in the first part ,but I have problem when username/pass correct  it's ok mais when it's incorrect I want to go back to form page but what i can get is just the dialog box

Comment: I create state with=true ;then when I press the button I changed to false ;In my render I check if It's false I show the dialog box ,else the form